# How to get my loop to pull posts into three columns

Tags: query, columns

I have my page template pulling one specific category & pulling the featured image & title into 3 different columns on my site. The problem is they all pull the CSS class .proj-left how can I get my page to pull the featured image, title, & use the specific column CSS class that should be assigned to it?

This is my page template:

```
<?php

/*

Template Name: Projects

*/

?>



<?php get_header(); ?>



<div id="content">
    <div id="contentwide">
        <div class="postarea_wide">


        <?php
        $counter = 1; //start counter

        $grids = 3; //Grids per row

        global $query_string; //Need this to make pagination work


        /*Setting up our custom query (In here we are setting it to show 12 posts per page and eliminate all sticky posts) */
        query_posts( array ( 'category_name' => 'decorating-home', 'posts_per_page' => 9 ) );


        if(have_posts()) :  while(have_posts()) :  the_post(); 
        ?>
        <?php
        //Show the left hand side column
        if($counter == 1) :
        ?>
                <div class="proj-left">
                                <div class="postimage">
                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('project-thumb'); ?></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="proj-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
                </div>
        <?php
        //Show the middle column
        elseif($counter == $grids) :
        ?>
                <div class="proj-middle">
                                <div class="postimage">
                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('project-thumb'); ?></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="proj-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
                </div>
        <?php
        //Show the right hand side column
        elseif($counter == $grids) :
        ?>
                <div class="proj-right">
                                <div class="postimage">
                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('project-thumb'); ?></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="proj-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
                </div>          

                <div class="clear"></div>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php
        endwhile;
        echo paginate_links( $args );
        endif;
        ?>



        </div>
    </div>
</div>



<!-- The main column ends  -->



<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Just as a note: This kind of layout can - and IMHO should - be done via CSS. No need to handle this via PHP. Or one can use the `Masonry` JS library, which is included in WP core, if some fancier features are needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, never use [`query_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts)

> **Note:** This function isn't meant to be used by plugins or themes. As explained later, there are better, more performant options to alter the main query. query_posts() is overly simplistic and problematic way to modify main query of a page by replacing it with new instance of the query. It is inefficient (re-runs SQL queries) and will outright fail in some circumstances (especially often when dealing with posts pagination).

If you can't use [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) to modify the main query properly, you must make use of either [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) or [`get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) to create a custom query with

You can achieve what you want with simple CSS and by clearing your float every third post by using the build in loop counter `$current_post`

You can modify your code to something like this

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Projects
*/
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="content">
    <div id="contentwide">
        <div class="postarea_wide">


        <?php
        /*Setting up our custom query (In here we are setting it to show 12 posts per page and eliminate all sticky posts) */
        $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
        $query = new WP_Query( array ( 'category_name' => 'decorating-home', 'posts_per_page' => 9, 'paged' => $paged ) );


        if($query->have_posts()) :  while($query->have_posts()) :  $query->the_post(); 
        ?>
            <div class="proj">
                            <div class="postimage">
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('project-thumb'); ?></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="proj-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
            </div>
        <?php       
            if(($query->current_post+1)%3 == 0){ 
                echo '<div class="clear" style="clear:left"></div>';
            }
        ?>

        <?php
        endwhile;
        echo paginate_links( $args );
        endif;
        ?>



        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- The main column ends  -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Your CSS can then look something like this

```
.proj {
   width: 33,3%;
   float: left:
}
```

**EDIT**

You are almost there with your pagination links.

For reference, see

- [`next_posts_link()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_posts_link)
- [`previous_posts_link`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/previous_posts_link)

Change your pagination link codes to the following

```
<div id="pagenav">
    <div class="prev"><p><?php previous_posts_link( 'Newer Entries' ); ?></p></div>
    <div class="next"><p><?php next_posts_link( 'Older Entries', $query->max_num_pages ); ?></p></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm getting this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' on line 20 thoughts? This is line 20:   if($query->have_posts()) :  $query->while(have_posts()) :  $query->the_post();

Comment: Goodmorning, Sorry about the syntax errors, I quickly posted before I went to bed. I fixed the syntax errors. See updated code :-)

Comment: Perfect! Everything seems to be working besides pagination now. I've added my links, but they don't show up. Thoughts? This is the updated code: http://pastebin.com/6c3UqEyz

Comment: Glad this worked out for you, please see my edit on pagination. Tested it and works. I'm off to bed now. Enjoy :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in a few ways, below I've laid out two.

**Method 1: Modulus**

The idea is that you get the remainder of your `$counter` divided by `$grids`. In our case, the left side will always be counted as: 1, 4, 7, 10, etc. so the remainder of our `$grid` (being 3) will always be 1. Our last column will be always equate to 0. At the bottom we must increment our `$counter`

```
if(have_posts()) :  while(have_posts()) :  the_post(); 
?>
<?php
//Show the left hand side column
if($counter % $grids = 1) :
?>
    <div class="proj-left">
        <div class="postimage">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('project-thumb'); ?></a>
        </div>
        <div class="proj-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
    </div>
<?php
//Show the middle column
elseif($counter % $grids = 2) :
?>
    <div class="proj-middle">
        <div class="postimage">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('project-thumb'); ?></a>
        </div>
        <div class="proj-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
    </div>
<?php
//Show the right hand side column
elseif($counter % $grids = 0) :
?>
    <div class="proj-right">
        <div class="postimage">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('project-thumb'); ?></a>
        </div>
        <div class="proj-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
    </div>          

    <div class="clear"></div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php $counter++;
endwhile;
```

**Method 2: Counter Reset**

Some people do not like modulus so in our 2nd method we could reset our counter each time it reaches 3. At that point we can just test if our `$counter` variable is equal to 1, 2, or 3.

```
if(have_posts()) :  while(have_posts()) :  the_post(); 
?>
<?php
//Show the left hand side column
if($counter == 1) :
?>
    <div class="proj-left">
        <div class="postimage">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('project-thumb'); ?></a>
        </div>
        <div class="proj-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
    </div>
<?php
//Show the middle column
elseif($counter == 2) :
?>
    <div class="proj-middle">
        <div class="postimage">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('project-thumb'); ?></a>
        </div>
        <div class="proj-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
    </div>
<?php
//Show the right hand side column
elseif($counter == 3) :
?>
    <div class="proj-right">
        <div class="postimage">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('project-thumb'); ?></a>
        </div>
        <div class="proj-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
    </div>          

    <div class="clear"></div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php $counter = ($counter == 3) ? 1 : ($counter + 1);
endwhile;
```

At the bottom of our loop is where we either increment our $counter or reset it back to 1.