# Masonry layout within the loop

Tags: php, wp-query

I have tried to to make a custom query, to some extend. it is working fine. But where i cannot make it work, is it to break after every 3 posts and do same thing (print div.row) and run same loop, For now, my code seem to output just 3 odd number posts, whereas i want it to break of after each 3 post.

```
if ($news->have_posts() ) : while ($news->have_posts() ) : $news->the_post();
    //$value = $news->current_post;
echo "<div class='col-lg-4'>";
    if($value % 3 == 0){
        ?>

                        <div class="height <?php foreach(get_the_category() as $category) { echo $category->slug . ' ';} ?>">
                        <div class="text">
                                <h5><?php the_time('F jS, Y'); ?></h5>
                                <h4><a href=""><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
                            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>


    <?php 
    //$i++;
    //print($value);
}
echo "</div>";
endwhile; endif;
```

Edit  : What is different about my layout, it should be in indivuial row, as shown in [bootly](http://www.bootply.com/render/90113), more like google cards layout.

Comment: @PieterGoosen what you mean

Comment: @PieterGoosen Thnx, i just updated it.

Comment: Check the two answers to [this question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/163176/31545)

Comment: @PieterGoosen I tried that now, but my post shows one after another, which isn't what i want. I want layout like [this] (http://www.bootply.com/90113)

Comment: @PieterGoosen my code display right, it is that wrapping of div that is now right, that i want to ask. where i want my div to display like [this] (http://www.bootply.com/90113)

Comment: @PieterGoosen What make my need different is, i want to load the rows as individual height then other rows, as shown in the link i pasted.

Comment: @PieterGoosen That's the word for it. I will edit my question to put that in. Now question is how to within php loop using wordpress.

Comment: there aren't any rows in the example you linked, it's just 3 columns.

Comment: @Milo Excuse my english, yes the columns, they have these masnory sort of layout, that is what i want.

Answer (score 0):

try this. i am not sure it would work for masonary layout or not. but it would give you an idea on how to make rows and columns within loop.

```
if ($news->have_posts() ) : while ($news->have_posts() ) : $news->the_post();
    //$value = $news->current_post;

    if($value % 3 == 0){
        ?>
      <div class="row">                 
        echo "<div class='col-lg-4'>";

                        <div class="height <?php foreach(get_the_category() as $category) { echo $category->slug . ' ';} ?>">
                        <div class="text">
                                <h5><?php the_time('F jS, Y'); ?></h5>
                                <h4><a href=""><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
                            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>


    <?php 
    //$i++;
    //print($value);
}
echo "</div>";
if($value % 3 !== 0){
echo "<div class='col-lg-4'>";
echo "</div">
}
endwhile; endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to achieve the same effect using CSS and `display:flex` - I don't think you need to break your loop up into threes.